# Visual Studio 2015 stucks while saving xaml

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I've been using Visual Studio 2015 for 2 months.
And i often run into with following problem:
VS 2015 stucks while saving xaml file (it doesn't fall with exception just show infinite saving animation).
I use ssd disk, and i don't use ReSharper.
This problem happens only on VS 2015.
Does somebody know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Any news on this?  Mine has starting to do it this evening with update 2.  File been saved plenty of times this evening.  Under TFS source control too.

Comment: @Andez i disabled xaml designer and it helped me